# strongly balanced and balanced graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph. define $d(G) = \frac{e(G)}{v(G)}$ and on the other hand, define $d_1(G) = \frac{e(G)}{v(G)-1}$.

> G is a **balanced graph**, if $d(H) < d(G)$ for all $H\subsetneq G$

> G is a **strongly balanced graph**, if $d_1(H)\leq d_1 (G)$ for all $H\subseteq G$.

I managed to prove that if G is strongly balanced graph it is necessarily a balanced graph. I need to show that the other way around is not true, That is exists a graph G which it is balanced but not strongly balanced.

Notice, we need to find a balanced graph G ( hence $d(H) < d(G)$ for all $H\subsetneq G$ ), which is not strongly balanced ( hence there exists a subsgraph $H\subseteq G$ where $d_1(H) > d_1(G) $ ).

Comment: Can you clarify the notation of $e(G)$ and $v(G)$? Are they cardinalities of the edge and vertex sets accordingly?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur (G) and v(G) are the amount of edges and vertices in the graph, respectfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {11}6>\frac 95$, but $\frac {11}5<\frac 94$. So if a graph with six vertices and eleven edges has a subgraph with five vertices and nine edges, it can't be strongly balanced but could still be balanced.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always checked graphs with more vertices than edges, and totally forgot to try those with more edges. Thank you!!!

Comment: And by the way, $\frac{7}{4}$ is greater than $\frac{5}{3}$, but anyways your comment helped me so much. consider fixing your answer so it could help other people too :)

Comment: @Kevinlove Thanks, have changed to a true statement :)